# GORM GOLANG/Go msSQL UNIQUEIDENTIFIER inside struct

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

Hello I have the struct like here named person and when I call my rest endpoint and get data from mssql database (where ID is
ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() )

```
package entities import ( mssql "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" "time" )
type Person struct { 
ID mssql.UniqueIdentifier 
FullName string Comments
string DateCreated time.Time 
DateModified time.Time
}
```

then golang return response with array of number
when I change ID to string its have unreadable chars.
bad response
after call like api from I get

```
{ "ID": [ 160,63, 67,62,243,107,20,16,143,174,0, 45,192,113,147,0 ],
"FullName": "Tony Stark",
"Comments": "",
"DateCreated": "2022-04-06T10:12:18.523Z",
"DateModified": "2022-04-06T10:12:18.523Z" 
}
```

I would like have response like

```
{ "ID": "a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11",
"FullName": "Tony Stark",
"Comments": "",
"DateCreated": "2022-04-06T10:12:18.523Z",
"DateModified": "2022-04-06T10:12:18.523Z" }
```

```
func Getperson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
var persons []entities.person
database.Instance.Raw("SELECT * FROM Persons").Scan(&person)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(person)
}
```

```
func Connect(connectionString string) {
    //dsn := "sqlserver://sa:*****@127.0.0.1:1433?database=mydbforgo"
    Instance, err = gorm.Open(sqlserver.Open(connectionString), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        panic("Cannot connect to DB")
    }
    log.Println("Connected to Database...")
}
```

where I have a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually want to call `.String` (eg: `someStruct.uniqueID.String()`) on that value in order to get the string representation of the GUID: https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/uniqueidentifier.go#L72-L80

Answer (score 0):

implement interface MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) like this:

```
type MyUniqueIdentifier struct {
    mssql.UniqueIdentifier
}

func (mu MyUniqueIdentifier) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) {
    return []byte(mu.String()), nil
}
```

then, change your struct:

```
type Person struct { 
  ID MyUniqueIdentifier 
  FullName string Comments
  string DateCreated time.Time 
  DateModified time.Time
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [unique identifier](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/uniqueidentifier.go) you're using is actually a 16 sized byte array `[16]byte`. You would need to cast it into a string to print it in a human readable format:

```
id := string(person.ID)
log.Info("ID: " + id)
```